# Regex to find all characters before and after first underscore, then make sure they are the same

Tags: java, regex

I have these two strings

```
2014_UMW
2014_UMW_web
```

I need to write a regex to get the character before and after the fist underscore. Then I need to make sure that they are both the same. I am checking to make sure that 2014_UMW is at the beginning of both strings. 2014_UMW is only one example. It could be `2015_YYY` and `2015_YYY_web` etc.

This the is regex that I am using `(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)` and then I am using pattern and matcher methods to see if they are both the same, but it is not working right. I have also tried this regex `[a-zA-Z_0-9]+[^_]+(?=_)`.

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/d90mU2) - is that what you are looking for? The regex is [`(_.).*+`](https://regex101.com/r/fG6eW6/1) that matches what you do not need to compare, thus, in a replaceAll, it can be removed, and the beginning of strings are compared.

Comment: Are you looking for comparing the whole of the string before the first underscore ?

Comment: There are three files in the directory 2014_UMW.fer, 2014_UMW.itm, and 2014_UMW_web.xml    I need to make sure all three files are associated with 2014_UMW, but since that one file has an extra _web after it is making it difficult. Another example would 2015_UMWXYZ.fer 2015_UMWXYZ.itm and 2015_UMWXYZ_web.xml. I need a regular expression to get me the beginning part of each file ie 2014_UMW or 2015_UMWXYZ in these two cases so I can make the three files are all associated with the same data set

Answer (score 0):

To get the part after first `_` you can use this regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^_]+_([^_]+)");
```

and get the captured group #1 using `matcher.group(1)` for the part your're interested in.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oV6vK3/1)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you say you are using, `(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)`, matches a non-empty sequence of characters other than `'_'` that is bounded on each side by an underscore.  That's nothing like your intent to "get the character before and after the [first] underscore".

From your example, I *think* what you mean to do is split the strings at underscores, and compare the first two segments of each.  In that case, you might consider using `String.split()`.  Details could vary depending on exactly how you want to characterize the splitting, but here's one, simple, way it might go:

```
String[] parts1 = string1.split("_");
String[] parts2 = string2.split("_");
// compare elements of parts1 and parts2
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a regex to *capture* the first two segments of such a string, then you want a `Pattern` along these lines:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([^_]+)_([^_]+)(?:_.*)?");
```

(That form is suitable for use with any of `Matcher.matches()`, `Matcher.find()`, or `Matcher.lookingAt()`; simpler forms are possible if you only want to support one or both of the latter two.)  Again, details of the needed pattern may vary depending on exactly what you're after.